# getting messages from browser into HTTP server in java

Tags: java, http, server

I'm trying to write a server in java that will hold a sort of database for registered students. Only need to take care of "add" ,"remove" and "getinfo".

I'm building up the the server access through the browser in "http://localhost/students/"

Now, I'm trying to send a request to the server by typing:
http://localhost/students/add?id=12324&name=Israel Israeli&gender=male&grade=90

I want to know how can i catch this message to parse it and do everything I need with it, I tried to use sockets but I don't know if I'm doing it right.
this is the code of the server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Httpserver {

public static RequestHandler _handler;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public Httpserver(){
    this._handler = new RequestHandler("welcome");
}
public static void setUp()  {
    HttpServer server;
    try {
        server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(80), 40);
        server.createContext("/students",_handler);
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
}
```

This is the code for the main application that runs everything:

```
public class Manager {

private Server _server;
private ArrayList<Student> _students;
private Parser _parser;

public Manager(){
    _server = new Server();
    _students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    _parser = new Parser();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void setUpServer(){
    _server.start();

    try {
        //ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(0);
        Socket getRequests = new Socket("localhost", 80);
        BufferedReader buff =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader      (getRequests.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out1 =
                new PrintWriter(getRequests.getOutputStream(), true);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(getRequests.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader stdIn =
                new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String  line;
        while (true){
            line =  buff.readLine();    
            out1.println(line);
            if (line == null){
                out.writeBytes("Connection ended");
                break;
            }
            int response = _parser.parseRequest();
            switch (response){
            case 1: handleAdd(_parser.getParams(), out);

            case 2: handleRemove(_parser.getParams(), out);

            case 3: handleGet(_parser.getParams(), out);
            }

        }
        getRequests.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //STODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
private void handleGet(ArrayList<String> params, DataOutputStream out) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void handleRemove(ArrayList<String> params, DataOutputStream out) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void handleAdd(ArrayList<String> params, DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (params == null || params.get(0) == "" ){
        out.writeBytes("id is mandatory for creating new student");
        return;
    }
    Student s;
    if (params.size() == 4){
        s = new Student(Long.parseLong(params.get(0)),
                params.get(1), params.get(2), Double.parseDouble(params.get(3)));
    }else{
        s = new Student(Long.parseLong(params.get(0)));
    }
    _students.add(s);
    out.writeBytes("student: " + s.getId() + " was added to the system");

}



public static void main(String[] args){
    Manager m = new Manager();
    m.setUpServer();
}
```

}

Not everything is implemented yet, I'm just trying to figure out how to capture the message from the browser and send a response back to the browser.
Thanks

Comment: I think you should reshape your idea. Instead of developing a full server, why don't you use a lightweight application server (like Jetty) and just implement the businness logic of your application, without tampering with HTTP specifics ?

Comment: It seems you are trying to add a student in response to a `GET` request, which is wrong. The `GET` request is ought to be idempotent. Also, passing around the data as request parameters is bad practice for various reasons. I suggest you look up some example which implements similar semantics in a clean manner and learn from there.

Comment: @BigMike I was asked to implement an HTTP server so I'm trying to it that way..

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. If trying out these kind of things isn't part of what you want to achieve, I would recommend looking into jetty/tomcat and REST.